# block access to certain pages in magento

Tags: php, magento

i have a category in my store, lets call it **Program**, this category will only have 1 product, lets call it **Program product**, so, i've developed a module only to show this category and product, the view is diferent from the others categories, so, if i write in my browser the url
**myweb.com/index.php/program.html** or **myweb.com/index.php/program-product.html** i can see the custom categories page or the product view page and i don't want that, i want that if someone write this url he will be redirect to another one, how can i do that, if it is posible

thanks

Comment: you can do it by .htaccess and i think you can do it through zend framework which is what magento is based of if i remember correctly

Comment: well, what about .htaccess, do you have an example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Do you want the category to show in the category menu but link to your new URL and not show in the old one?"
>
> "yeah, this is exactly what i want, is this possible??"

Try this; Go to the menu *Catalog > URL Rewrite Management* and find the entry for your category. Crucially it's target path will look something like "catalog/category/view/id/123" ('catalog' is the module, 'category' is the controller, 'view' is the action and 'id/123' is a parameter).

Follow [these URL rewrite instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/seo/how_to_work_with_magento_url_rewrite_rules) to delete the above entry then create a replacement. It's only difference will be the target path, use your module's path along with whichever controller, action and parameters are suitable for this case.

By preserving the *ID Path* of the old rewrite rule you are ensuring it doesn't get overwritten, although I haven't tested this with rebuilding indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Does the category's enabled setting, and the product's visibility setting affect your module's display? If not use those settings to hide them from the catalog but continue using your module as normal.

Comment: i already tried this, if a change the enabled setting of the category, then i can see it in the categories menu, another way?

Comment: Do you want the category to show in the category menu but link to your new URL and not show in the old one?

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what i want, is this possible??